# JAR file messes GUI?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jar

I've got some homework to make a simple login window.
After I finished with my coding I tried exporting the file into a runnable jar file, and after running the jar file I saw that it had messed up the GUI.
The JPasswordField fills up my entire JFrame for some reason. I have no clue what might be the problem because it runs fine from the IDE. any help?

[image: What I want it to look like]

[image: What it looks like when I run the JAR]

here is the code (works fine in eclipse IDE):`

```
public class Login extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static JTextField user = new JTextField();
private static JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField();
private static JButton Loginbtn = new JButton("Login");
protected String[] args;
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log In");


public Login(){

    Loginbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(user.getText().equals("Admin") && pass.getText().equals("Nimda")){

                //System.out.println("Hello ADMIN!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged In!");
                MyLog.main(args);
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{

                //System.out.println("Login error!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Error!");
            }
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Login login = new Login();
    JLabel username = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Password");

    frame.setSize(260, 200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    username.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
    password.setBounds(20, 85, 100, 20);
    pass.setBounds(85, 85, 150, 20);
    user.setBounds(85, 60, 150, 20);
    Loginbtn.setBounds(88, 110, 50, 20);

    frame.add(username);
    frame.add(password);
    frame.add(Loginbtn);
    frame.add(user);
    frame.add(pass);

}          
}
```

thanks in advance guys!
cheers!

Comment: Don't modify the bounds of your controls that are already under the control of a layout manager.

Comment: See also [*How do I create screenshots?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling setVisible on the JFrame before adding your components to it causes the problem most likely. You should add all the components that you want to the JFrame before calling setVisible, as setVisible validates those components (lays them out).

[What setVisible does from the API, you'll see it talks about validating the components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)

[What validate does from API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29)